# JAVA -JAR is returning Version description

Tags: java, jar

I have made jar file from IntelliJ using build artifact but instead of running code it returns the version description

"java -jar Filename.jar"

Implementation Version: 58.1
Unicode Data Version:   9.0
CLDR Data Version:      30.0.2
Time Zone Data Version: 2016g

Comment: Which jar should it execute ? You need to specify the file in the command

Comment: i am specifying that

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you forgot to add the file name in the comandline

```
java -jar <filename>
```